# FAT32 and exFAT, which file timestamps are supported?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, fat32, exfat

is it true that the FAT32 only supports these file timestamps?

- Creation time (birth time)
- Modified time
- Change time
- Access time does not exist on FAT32.

With exFAT all 4 timestamps are supported:

- Creation time (birth time)
- Modified time
- Change time
- Access time

It would be good to know how the behavior is on current Windows 10 (20H2) and it has been tested in real.

Comment: No FAT* file system supports change time (and in fact, even for NTFS that does, Microsoft [isn't](https://web.archive.org/web/20120721045854/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290(VS.85).aspx) officially acknowledging it).. Anyhow you should note that once upon a time Linux used to set those fields with an [entirely](https://dfir.ru/2021/12/08/things-you-probably-didnt-know-about-fat/) different/wrong meaning in vfat, and even across different Windows versions there are some [quirks](https://www.giac.org/paper/gcfa/570/reverse-engineering-microsoft-exfat-file-system/106672#page=41).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the file system is FAT32, the entry of last access time cannot be written, or be changed.

The specifications of the exFAT file system include:

Timestamp granularity of 10 ms for Create and Modified times (down from 2 s of FAT, but not as fine as NTFS's 100 ns)

Timestamp granularity for Last Access time to double seconds (FAT had date only).

Timestamps come with a time zone marker in offset relative to UTC (starting with Vista SP2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Do you also know about change time, so in NTFS is change time -> MFT Entry modified. Is it also supported in FAT32 and exFAT or is there not?

Other question do you know if there is file manager (GUI) on Windows 10 (20H2) where I can see all 4 timestamps regardless if the file system stores the timestamps or not?

Comment: Such attribute [should](https://dfir.ru/2019/01/19/ntfs-today/) exist for NTFS, and [`fsutil`](https://serverfault.com/a/923013/356620) should be able to display it. But it simply [isn't](https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/journal-home/journal/jips/fullText/758/jips_18_3_10.pdf#page=3) there on FAT file systems, that are all more or less "architecturally" [identical](http://lockandcode.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/LockCode-Computer-Forensic-Examiner-Quick-Reference-Guide-Version-2.0-Sample.pdf#page=24) (you can also see how *i_ctime=i_mtime* in the Linux's driver source code).